# How to design rounded layout with border and fix its children within the border

Tags: android, xml

I  need to design this button in Android.
[image: How to design this in android?]

I could not fix the 'x' icon inside the parent layout's border.

This is my roundedview's layout (textview_filter_sortby.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#636363" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />


    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

This is what I have tried doing:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_filter_sort_by">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="India"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        android:background="#cbcbcb"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I got this as my result:
[image: My result]

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried and what is the output you have got out of it ?

Comment: Done. Please check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

create resource file in drawable folder and paste this code inside the created file. It will round the button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

in xml at button tag use background="@drawable/yourdrawable"

Next:

Use drawableRight attribute to your button like this.

```
android:drawableRight="@drawble/your_image"
```

If you want to give padding to the drawable, then use

```
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

### You will need to check [Shape Drawables](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDrawables/article.html)

Define a TextView in your layout file and set the background as custom shape

e.g.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounder_rectangle"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

**rounder_rectangle.xml** put this in your **/drawable** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#DDBBBBBB"
        android:startColor="#DD777777"
        android:angle="90" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

**Based on your requirement, You will need to fix your code as**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounder_rectangle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="India"
        android:id="@+id/name"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        android:background="#cbcbcb"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What about the 'X' icon and its background?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_border_rectangle">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:text="helloasdasdas" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_text"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_rect"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/close" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**shapes1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGray" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dimen_10dp" />
</shape>
```

**shapes2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorCardBackGround" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/dimen_1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorCardBackGround" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/dimen_10dp" />
</shape>
```